# Mongo DB - Error when trying to create a AND condition

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to build a AND condition while filtering in mongo DB but get the below error:

```
db.mycol.find({$and: 
[{"description" : "MongoDB is no sql database"}]  
,[{"likes" : 100}]})
```

Error message is:

```
2019-02-06T17:10:57.403+0530 E QUERY    
[js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:88
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error and query should be

```
db.mycol.find({$and: 
[{"description" : "MongoDB is no sql database"} ,{"likes" : 100}]});
```

All the filters should be in `{}` inside the `[]` not each in a separate list.